# using Kendo UI with sencha touch

Tags: ios, sencha-touch-2, kendo-ui

I am developing html 5 app with native look of ios/android.
I want to know: is it possible to use kendoUI along with sencha touch 2.0.

Advanced thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KendoUI Mobile would be an alternative for Sencha Touch.

The thing is both are frameworks for making Mobile Development easier.

In case, you wanted to use KendoUI DataViz with Sencha, I think its possible, though I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Which component? KendoUI is broken into three parts:

**KendoUI Mobile** is a set of cross-OS widgets that make developing mobile UIs easier. I've not used Sencha, but it looks at least on par with KendoUI in this area.

**KendoUI DataViz** is a set of data visualization tools. They support both desktop and mobile devices.

**KendoUI Web** is a set of cross-browser widgets, mostly for web application building.

You could use DataViz with Sencha, but I'm not sure what you would gain. Sencha Touch Charts seems to be on par or better than KendoUI DataViz, and they are designed for mobile first.

Comment: KendoUI Mobile is a set of cross-OS widgets that make developing mobile UIs easier. I've not used Sencha, but it looks at least on par with KendoUI in this area.